# Devexpress SearchlookUpEdit search mode

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm using Devexpress SearchLookUpEdit V 11.2. And For the search mode, if I write for example (Value01 Value02) it works like the following sql Code :

```
WHERE MyField LIKE %Value01% OR MyField LIKE %Value02%
```

But what I want to do, is like this : (AND, not OR)

```
WHERE MyField LIKE %Value01% AND MyField LIKE %Value02%
```

I didn't find a property to set or something like that, so I wrote a extension method who filter my data for me, but for that, I should handle the event of (typing in the find panel). Where to do that ? and is this the right way to filter my data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did to have such behavior is the following :
Create a user control using `PopupContainerEdit`, `PopupContainerControl` and a `GridControl` :

[image: User control : Custom lookup edit]

I've also handled the EditValueChanged event of my PopupContainerEdit by executing my search method, and to have some control on when the search algorithm should be executed, i've used a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Answer (score 0):

There is a option for search mode like contain,start with ... Go to properties change popupfilterMode.